# jQuery trigger('click') problem

Tags: jquery

I have clickable row, that will fire link `onclick` event, but `trigger()` cause a new click event on `tr.clickable` and go into loop. How to prevent this ?

```
<table>
    <tr class="clickable">
        <td>Test row</td>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="alert('click');" class="trigger"></a></td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
$('tr.clickable').click(function(){
    var trigger = $(this).find('a.trigger');
    trigger.trigger('click');
});
```

Live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fg6za/).

Comment: Why are you trying to do what you are doing? @simoncereska has the right answer, but the reasoning might be wrong depending on what you are actually trying to do. You've specifically told it to get itself into a loop....

Comment: I need something like that: user clicks a row, the onclick function for inner `<a href... />` is called **only once** and done.

Comment: In that case @Matt has the right approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is down to event bubbling in JavaScript. It's a bit of a weird setup you've got at the moment, but one way to fix it would be to stop the `click` event bubbling on the `a` tag:

```
$('tr.clickable a').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nhd8p/)

Alternately you could not fire the `click` trigger if the target event is the same element:

```
$('tr.clickable').click(function(e){
    var trigger = $(this).find('a.trigger').not(e.target);
    trigger.trigger('click');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nhd8p/1/)

The best way would probably be the first solution, I guess.

Comment: I would replace the onclick with $('td .trigger').click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); alert('click'); }); It is a good practice to not use inline javascript.

Answer (score 2):

remove `trigger.trigger('click');` and thats it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
    $('tr.clickable').click(function(){
         alert('Click');
 });
```

Live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fg6za/10/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the event parameter, to check what is the target of the click.

```
$('tr.clickable').click(function(e){
  if (e.target.nodeName != 'A') {
    var trigger = jQuery(this).find('a.trigger');
    trigger.trigger('click');
  }
});
```